# aspnet StaticFileHandlers cause resources in bundles to 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I am integrating an existing ASPNET MVC 5.2.4 site with a NuGet package that delivers static file resources in its assemblies.

This package is an internal package in my company but I don't have access to the dev who built this.

There is a handler section in the Web.Config

`<add verb="GET" path="*.js" name="Static for js" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
 <add verb="GET" path="*.css" name="Static for css" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />`

If I comment out the static file handler then my original site CSS works and the imported assembly style is lost.

There is also an RegisterVirtualPathProvider that loads the assemblies on startup which seems to be working correctly.

My question is this. What should I be looking at to solve this issue? Is the Virtaul Path Provider changing the default path where the css/js in bundles are being looked for?

I only have a little experience in MVC.

EDIT: It seems only files in the css folder are being published. So I have a workaround to change if needed but I still don't understand why I lose the files in bundles with different paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local CSS files were placed under a folder that ended in .CSS or .JS
e.g. ABCD.CSS/*.css etc...

This meant that the 's added for GET requests to handle path="*.css" would fail.

I renamed the folders and all is well